# Jquery Drag and Drop in nested lists - how to minimise / remove the flicker

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

Based on http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#placeholder I am working on a drag and drop interface that allows the user to reorganise nested lists. As you can see from [the link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#placeholder) this works great on simple lists.

However, when I try it with nested lists, I get quite bad flickering. Try it for yourself at:

http://jsfiddle.net/unklefolk/G5xPE/

After moving some inner items to the outer list and visa-versa you will see that there is quite a bit of flickering / dithering happening, particularly around the point where an outer list meets and inner list.

**What can I do to minimise this flickering? Are there any change to the jQuery or CSS that I can make that would reduce this problem?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at this nested sortable plugin.  It is list item driven, but it may be the answer to your issue.

[nestedSortable jQuery Plugin](http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/)

Comment: Great link Brian. This plugin seems a lot more like what I need. Wish I had found this several months ago. I may not be able to use this solution as I am pretty far down the jQuery UI route and time is limited but I will award this answer the bounty as it seems the best solution for other SO users who encounter this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Usually i use `helper: 'clone'` wich has some impact on this problem (never understood why).i don't know if it works, on my firefox 8 looks better

```
$(function() {
    $( ".sortable" ).sortable({
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
        connectWith: ".sortable",
         helper: 'clone'
    });
    $( ".sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/G5xPE/17/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Nicola. Didn't seem to have much effect on my implementation but hopefully this will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once before, I don't have time to adapt it but here's my solution.

Use a js callback:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var s = $("#sortable");
    s.sortable({
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            var ranks = ['gold','silver','bronze'];
            $("li",s).each(function (idx) {
                for(var i = 0; i < ranks.length; ++i) $(this).removeClass(ranks[i]);
                $(this).addClass(ranks[idx]);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

You can see it [here in jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/wpPLC/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Kyle. Unfortunately, I have taken your fiddle, extended it to nested lists and still get the flicker as I move between levels. http://jsfiddle.net/unklefolk/uueFC/ Not sure if I'm missing something?

Comment: The fiddle you provided doesn't have a nested list :)

Comment: Apologies. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/unklefolk/uueFC/3/ I'm afraid I've lost the nice chocolate bar images but I think it is in essence the same.

Answer (score 0):

OP here. Just wanted to post what I finally did to fix this. Based on http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4741?cversion=0&cnum_hist=8 I **uncommented** the following line in jquery-ui-1.8.6.js:

```
&& itemElement.parentNode == this.placeholder[0].parentNode // only rearrange items within the same container
```

I still use the `connectWith` attribute.

I can now drag and drop between levels in the hierarchy with no flicker. Hope this helps other SO users.

Comment: what if we are using jQuery ui 1.12.1 ? @Mark